# Huge XML to Model in C#

Tags: c#

I am working with a huge XML using a tool in VS2010 able to convert it into a Model (.cs class). Now in order to read that XML, I am parsing through the tags and filling in my objects  in the Model.
Just want to know if I am on the right track or there's a easier way to now load the Model with xml data

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Deserialize XML document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to do this for you.

```
using(StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("FilePath"))
{
   XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyModel));
   MyModel model = serial.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: It's `XmlSerializer` - you've mis-spelled it every time you've used it.

Comment: That's Tuesdays for ya

Comment: Sometimes they're worse than Mondays!